# Show text exactly how it is displayed in the text document

Tags: formatting

I have the following bit of text that I want to show :

> A =
>
> ```
>  9    -8     7
>  6    -5    -4
>  3    -2     1
> ```

I want to show it exactly as it is, i.e. no formatting.

Currently it shows :

[image: screen]

I assume there is an environment that avoids any formatting but I've been unable to find it.

(I don't want to create a matrix in the math environment, because that's log that I want to show as it is.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest that you parse the log file so that you may typeset it as a proper matrix.

Anyway, if you don't want to do any formatting you can use the environment `verbatim`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
A =

 9    -8     7
 6    -5    -4
 3    -2     1
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: You don't need the `verbatim` package for this.